# Cannot run Flutter App on Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I'm using Android Studio to create Flutter application. It works perfectly on iOS simulators, however, I cannot run it on Android emulators.

[image: iOS]
As you can see in the screenshot, I can see my iPhone 8 simulator but I cannot see Android emulator, although I'm running "Pixel 2" emulator.

You can see my virtual devices in the screenshot below.

[image: Android]

**Update 1:**

This is the output of `flutter doctor`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.3.2, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E202, locale en-KW)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 26.0.2)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.23.1)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Try `killall -9 dart` and `adb kill-server`

Comment: I tried. Didn't work.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `flutter doctor`?

Comment: Do you see any log-msgs in the 'logcat' window that seem suspicious, when you try to debug using an Android emulator?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have updated the post and added the output of `flutter doctor`.

Comment: It's really weird that AS doesn't list the emulators you created in the drop-down (where `iPhone 8` is listed)

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Any updates?

Answer (score 21):

#### Short answer

Probably the **Project SDK** is not set. Set it from Android Studio;

- **File -> Project Structure** -> *Project Settings -> Project*

---

#### Longer answer

I had the same issue;

- `flutter doctor` command says everything is OK
- AVDs are created with Android Studio's AVD Manager
- Android Studio shows no devices to run app on

I realized that Flutter's doctor can be also run from Android Studio (**Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Doctor**) and it had a problem with Android toolchain; said that SDK is not set. I am not sure how this doctor has different output from `flutter doctor` run from the project's directory, but it was the correct one. I just went to **File -> Project Structure** and under *Project Settings -> Project* selected the appropriate **Project SDK** - Android API xx Platform (was `<No-SDK>`).

Comment: This woked for me. It seem Android Studio doesn't know for what sdk emulator looking for... thanks